# What is the meaning of || '|' || in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I see a query with  this "`COUNT(DISTINCT(code || '|' description)`":

```
SELECT ...,..., ...,NULL, COUNT(DISTINCT(code || '|' description)
FROM....
```

But Im not understanding what this "`COUNT(DISTINCT(code || '|' description)`" means? Do you know what it is? Thanks

Comment: When posting code that you don't understand, please make sure that you copy-and-paste it correctly. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.)

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, the double pipe (`||`) stands for string concatenation. This:

```
select 'a' || 'b' from dual
```

Yields:

```
ab
```

When it comes to this expression: `COUNT(DISTINCT(code || '|' description)`:

- it is invalid sql code: parentheses are not balanced, and there is a missing concatenation operator; I suppose you meant `COUNT(DISTINCT code || '|' || description)`
- the latter concatenates `code` and `description` with a `|` separator, and counts distinct resulting values

Answer (score 3):

|| is the string concatenation operator

This code has a slight syntax error but looks like it was supposed to concat the code column with the description column values separated by a pipe

```
code, description
A123, code for blah blah
```

Becomes:

```
A123|code for blahblah
```

(If the sql is amended to `code || '|' || description`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you intend:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT code || '|' || description)
```

The purpose of this code is to count the unique combinations of `code` and `description`.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in Oracle takes only one argument.  So, if you want to count distinct combinations, you need to resort to tricks such as concatenating the values together.

This is putting the values together with a vertical bar in-between:

```
'NY' || '|' || 'New York' --> 'NY|New York'
```

The vertical bar is a separator that presumably does not occur (or only rarely occurs) in either `code` or `description`.